# Access IIS Express from Web API from

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2, windows-10-mobile

First let me say this used to work in Visual Studio 2015 but I am having the a darn hard time getting it to work in Visual Studio 2017.

I have a WebAPI project running in Visual Studio 2017.  I have edited the applicationhost.config file in the …\ProjectName.vs\config file so it has the following entries for my project.

```
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56952:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56952:192.168.1.155" />
            </bindings>
```

My firewall is completely disabled.  When I try to run my Xamarin forms project on a Win10 Mobile V10.0.15254.0 emulator my app does not connect to the WebAPI.  (I get the standard "The text associated with this error code could not be found.  A connection with the server could not be established."

If I launch Edge on the emulator and try to access any of my local servers on the network using IP address, that works.  Can someone enlighten me with regard to what has changed and how I can now make this work?

Comment: are you using the IP from the XF project?  Can you access your service endpoint from Edge in the emulator?

Comment: Yes - the URL for the WebAPI in my XF project is a shown above -http://192.168.1.155:56952.  No I cannot access the WebAPI directly from the Edge browser on the emulator using that same (or any form) of the URL.

Comment: that sounds like a networking issue

Comment: Well there are known configuration items that need to be set up for the emulator to access the WebAPI on the local machine - this is already know.  It has worked before.  I am simply asking if that setup has changed with VS 2017 as now I can no longer access the WebAPIs in debug mode in visual studio.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue. You need to whitelist your portno 56952 in your firewall. Your mobile

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was the IP address I was using.  Here are the steps I used to resolved this:

1. I launched my Windows 10 mobile emulator.
2. Click on the >> (Tools) icon in the tool bar of the emulator.
3. Click on the Network tab of the Additional Tools window.
4. I looked in the list for the network adaptor labeled Desktop Adaptor #1 and copied the IP address.
5. Edit the Applicationhost.config file in the folder of the WebAPI project.
6. Find the entry in the file for site name="XXXXX" where XXXXX is the name of the Visual Studio project you are hosting your WebAPIs in.
7. Within the `<bindings>` section of the entry for your WebAPI project, add a binding for the IP address you copied from in step 4.  It should look something like this:

   ```
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56952:169.254.69.220" />
   ```

Where 56952 is the port my IIS Express is hosting the WebAPIs on and 169.254.69.220 is the IP address I copied from step 4.

After adding this, I was able to connect to locally hosted WebAPIs in IIS Express.

Hope this helps.